# titanium youtube video autoplay

Tags: youtube, titanium-mobile

I have the following code to show youtube video in titanium for iOS.

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow();


// Set the window orientation modes for the video to rotate with the device
win.orientationModes = [ Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT,
                     Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT ];

win.open();

// Build the movie URL. 'fs' and 'autoplay' parameters are optional.
var movieId = "oYgMRIIVX3w";
var movieUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + movieId+ "?fs=1&autoplay=1";
webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
url : movieUrl
});

win.add(webview);
```

However, even use the "autoplay=1", the youtube video is still not playing automatically. User still need to click on the play button in youtube.

Any idea on how to play the youtube automatically without clicking the play button?

Thanks.

Comment: This has to deal more with the iPhone SDK rather than Titanium itself. You're creating a web element that contains a frame where a user is able to view the video. Now because iPhone SDK doesn't directly have Flash, it kind of transposes this frame into its own thing. That's why the user still has to press the play button in order to view the video.